# Go cannot find packages in go/pkg looking in go/src

Tags: go, go-modules

trying to work with GoLang and MQTT but go seems unable to find the packages.

```
% go version
go version go1.16.7 darwin/amd64
```

foobar.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
    mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)
```

when trying to run I would get the following error

```
go run foobar.go
foobar.go:9:2: no required module provides package github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

```
% go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/{user}/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/{user}/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/{user}/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.7"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/rg/80kn_qfn0_91cv0_fb43_m5r0000gn/T/go-build2547135435=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I set $GOPATH and $GOROOT to match the go env. I even tried going back to the old path method by setting GO111MODULE="off", but that resulted in this error

```
% go run foobar.go
foobar.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/{user}/go/src/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang (from $GOPATH)
```

I am confused because `go get/install github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang` appears to be installing of my packages are being installed under go/pkg/ while the above output and all the documentation I read says indicated the /src so why do I have the /pkg directory.

Answer (score 5):

Please use modules. You should not be setting `GOROOT` or `GOPATH`.

I recommend going through the following path, using official documentation pages:

1. Read about [properly installing Go for your platform](https://golang.org/doc/install).
2. Read the [getting started tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) which also tells you how to install 3rd-party packages and use them in your code.

It should take you no more than 20 minutes to go through these steps, and it's almost certain that you'll be able to accomplish your goal by the end of the process. As a bonus, keep going through the Getting Started guide beyond the first page to learn how to create your own Go modules, use them from other modules, write tests, `build` your code into a binary, and more.

This is IMHO the minimal background required to even try writing Go programs; without going through these steps, you will lack crucial fundamental understanding and it will be hard to even understand SO answers.

Comment: First thank you for taking your time for a novice question. I did get things to work for me but I am still confused. I read the documentation and don't understand the [link](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-path) part about module (not package) paths. specifically module directive naming convention

Comment: @KevinRiordan: don't worry about reading that whole reference doc right now - just refer to it when specific questions arise. It's not clear to me what you don't understand specifically, but consider asking a separate question for that. Happy to hear the issue has been resolved